# pywinatuo - Access Database Match Error for the same property - Code works on a small database not on a large one

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I am trying to run some access queries using pywinauto. The error Constantly changes.

After checking the control properties i found that the query name does exist. However the the code throws an error stating match not found.

```
import os
import subprocess
access_file = r'C:\Ren'
filename='test.accdb'
accessPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.exe'
subprocess.Popen([accessPath,access_open])
dlg=Desktop(backend='uia').window(title_re='Access*')
sleep(10)
dlg.Navigation_Pane.Queries.Query1.invoke()
dlg.Yes.invoke()
print(dlg.print_control_identifiers())
```

This code works on a smaller database. I Tried it 1st on a large database and got errors so i created a test database with few tables and queries. It works fine.

When i change `dlg.Navigation_Pane.Queries.delete_reports.invoke()`
and change the path to the actual database. I get a `MatchError: Could not find 'Queries'`.

This is the control properties.

```
GroupBox - 'Queries'    (L4, T2979, R429, B5581)
   |    |    |    | ['Queries', 'QueriesGroupBox', 'GroupBox8', 'Queries0', 'Queries1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Queries", control_type="Group")

Button - 'delete report'    (L4, T3271, R429, B3301)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Button147', 'delete reportButton', 'delete report']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="delete report", control_type="Button")
```

I am unable to understand why does it one work on one database and does not on the other.

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: It might be timing issue. How long this “Queries” element appears? More than 5 seconds?

Comment: Could be the queries appear not the entire list dlg.wait also did not help much

Comment: @VasilyRyabov is there a way to wait until all the elements are loaded and then invoke them

Comment: i tried `dlg.Navigation_Pane.Queries.wait('ready', timeout=120)`. It works sometimes. Sometimes i get timeout error. Not sure how to set the system to automatically set the timer. so i dont get the time out message. `dlg.Navigation_Pane.Queries.wait('ready', timeout=120, retry_interval=5)`. This also did not work.

Comment: `ElementNotFoundError: {'title_re': 'delete_report', 'class_name': 'Button', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'Access - daily_report : Database- C:\daily_report.accdb (Access 2007 - 2013 file format)', OMain, 1444186>, 'backend': 'uia'}`.  Is the error when i use `dlg.window(title_re='delete_report',class_name='Button').invoke()`

Comment: You may try to wait for every element, but it's not what you want probably. There is `app.wait_cpu_usage_lower()` that waits till application specific CPU usage becomes below threshold. So you don't have to check every element, just wait while job is done from CPU point of view.

Comment: The docs: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html

Comment: @VasilyRyabov i tried the same as `dlg.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=10)`  i get `Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'wait_cpu_usage_lower' were found (typo?). .`

Comment: It's wrong usage. Method `wait_cpu_usage_lower` is available for `Application` object only, not for concrete elements.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Just to confirm i need to use it when i define `app = Application(backend="uia").start("Access.exe")` for it to work not like `dlg=Desktop(backend='uia').window(title_re='Access*')`. Are both not the same.

Comment: Desktop object is not the same. It’s not bound to particular process. And we don’t provide system wide CPU usage because it doesn’t make much sense: any random process may influence on this.